# How to validate parent component in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have a component, inside that there are 4-5 components. I want to disable the Save button if any of the form's mandatory fields are not selected or filled.

```html
<p-tabView>
    <p-tabPanel header="General" [selected]="true">
        <data-general [data]="data" (modalSave)="childData($event)">
        </data-general>
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Additional" *ngIf="this.isEditData">
        <data-additional [data]="data" (modalSave)="additionalValid($event)">
        </data-additional>
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Test" *ngIf="this.isEditData">
        <test-component></test-component>
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Test2" *ngIf="this.isEditData">
        <data-test2></data-test2>
    </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" 
     [disabled]="!isFormValid()" (click)="onSubmitBtnClick()">Save</button>
```

I tried to implement method `isFormValid`, define and check properties to check the validity of each form. but I'm not able to do.

`data-general`, `data-additional`, `test-component` and `data-test2` are the child components.

Comment: Can you show the component code please.

Comment: @JoeKeene parent or child component?

Comment: do you have a button in child component for passing data to parent component in the each child component like data-general etc ??

Comment: Both would be helpful

Comment: @JoeKeene what code you want to see, please be specific, because there is lot of code

Comment: Well your question is related to the function `isFormValid` so to start with the code for that function.

Comment: @Chandru not working dear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue, posting my solution so that it can help others.

Directive:

```
import { Directive } from "@angular/core";
import { NgForm, ControlContainer } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
    selector: '[provide-parent-form]',
    providers: [
        {
            provide: ControlContainer,
            useFactory: function (form: NgForm) {
                return form;
            },
            deps: [NgForm]
        }
    ]
})
export class ProvideParentForm { }
```

Parent component html:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!formName.valid">Save</button>
```

Child component html:
have a `div` instead of `form` in child component.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this :

**data-general.component.html**

```
<form name="dataGeneralForm" role="form" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(dataGeneralForm)" #dataGeneralForm="ngForm">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="data.name" name="name" id="name" required />
    <button type="submit">Children Button</button>
</form>
```

**data-general.component.ts**

```
export class DataGeneralComponent {

    data: any = {};

    @Output() modalSave = new EventEmitter();

    onSubmit(dataGeneralForm: NgForm) {
        this.modalSave.next(dataGeneralForm);
    }

}
```

**parent.component.html:**

```
<p-tabView>
    <p-tabPanel header="General" [selected]="true">
        <data-general (modalSave)="childData($event)"></data-general>
    </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!parentForm?.valid">Save</button>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

export class ParentComponent {
    parentForm: NgForm;

    childData(e) {
        this.parentForm = e;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no Children Button

Comment: I have submit button only in parent component.